# Segmentation fault in NULL check?

Tags: null, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault while trying to check if some elements are `NULL` or not. Can anyone help?

```
    void addEdge(int i, int j) 
{
        if (i >= 0 && j > 0) 
    {
        Node* whereto;
        whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[i];
        if(whereto != NULL)
        {
            while(whereto->adj != NULL)
            {whereto = whereto->adj;}
            whereto->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[j];
        }
        else{linkedAdjacencyList[i]->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[j];}
        whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[j];
        if(whereto != NULL)
        {
            while(whereto->adj != NULL)
            {whereto = whereto->adj;}
            whereto->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[i];
        }
        else{linkedAdjacencyList[j]->adj = linkedAdjacencyList[i];}
            }
    }
```

help!

EDIT: this is the new code, as per your suggestions, but now there is a segmentation fault immediately when the method is called? i'll post the calling...

```
int edges;
in >> edges;
g.edges = edges;
for(int i = 0; i < edges; i++)
{
    int first;
    int second;
    in >> first >> second;
    g.addEdge(first, second);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that `linkedAdjacencyList[i]` returns `NULL`, so you are trying to dereference `NULL`. Just add extra check for `NULL` :

```
Node* whereto = NULL;
whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[i];
if (NULL != whereto){
while(whereto->adj != NULL) .....
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to check whether `whereto` is being initialized properly in `whereto = linkedAdjacencyList[i];`.

Answer (score 0):

The expression `whereto -> adj != NULL` uses `whereto` as a pointer and dereferences it with `adj` at its offset from the beginning of the structure or class.  If that statement is segfaulting, it means `whereto` has a bad pointer value.  Check what comes out of `linkedAdjancencyList[]` and don't use it if NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Put an if check above the while loop and check whether whereto is NULL.

if(whereto!=NULL){
while(whereto->adj != NULL).........
}